# My webpage goes behind my header on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6Zg8.jpg)

My webpage goes behind the header  i have tried all the things but my content is still behind the header

Comment: Is too hard to tell, it could be any number of things. Do you have a link to the site? Or can paste the source code for the Html.

Comment: www.cleamba.com @GodisLove

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Find and Change the following CSS.

```css
.ast-theme-transparent-header #masthead {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Remove the position: absolute rule.

```css
.ast-theme-transparent-header #masthead {
  
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

There is other CSS you will have to adjust, but that stops the content from going behind the header. You will also need to adjust your Elementor content to have less padding.

Comment: any solution via wordpress dashboard

Comment: There could be, but it is impossible to tell. Look for your theme options in WordPress. But your theme is designed to have the content go behind the header.